# How are messages marked as read using discord.js?

Tags: discord.js

I've written a chat client extension for visual studio code, using the https://discord.js.org/ framework.

At the moment I'm tracking the last read message in each channel manually, but the message and channel objects have an 'acknowledge' method to mark them as read.

It seems that this should be the correct way to mark messages as read, but I can't work out how to determine which messages have been read when fetching the messages from the server?

Comment: Well, bots don't have messages that are read and messages that aren't.
If you are making a selfbot (or using the token from a user account), you might end up banned from Discord. Making a bot out of your account (sounds something you are doing) is not allowed according to Discord's TOS.

Comment: I'm not trying to make a bot, just using my account to post and read messages from a console window. According to the docs, the 'acknowledge' method is usable from user accounts, but not bots. I'll have a good look at the TOS - thanks.

Comment: I don't think there's any kind of property that tells you if a message has been read in discord.js :\
You could save the timestamps of the last read message for every channel, then if you fetch messages that are newer you mark the channel as read. That's the most accurate I think you can get...

Answer (score 0):

There are no events or any sort of way to see if a message was read sadly. It is a feature that I would like implemented, but for the time being there is no way to do it.

Wishing you luck,

Zaedus